# Why expressjs showing form data as string

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multipartform-data, angular12

Im sending formdata from angular app to expressjs API, but the data is being shown as a string in this format:

```
{
  '-----------------------------42441008406052765922228936908\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"webmasterfile"; filename="blob"\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: text/xml\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------42441008406052765922228936908\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testing2"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'something\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------42441008406052765922228936908--\r\n'
}
```

I've seen answers everywhere that said to parse data with express by including this line but its not working:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Heres my angular js code:

```
submitForm() {
    var formData = new FormData();

    var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml" });

    formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);
    formData.append('testing2', 'something')
    this.bookingService.newBooking(formData).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }
```

and this is the angular service:

```
private serverUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3001/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  newBooking(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      this.serverUrl + 'booking',
      data,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        ),
        withCredentials: true
      }
    );
  }
```

How can I get the data in express as an object so I could access the formdata values instead of a string?

Comment: in `req.body.webmasterfile` it wont magically parse the xml string you need to run it though a parser. Why not just send json?

Comment: I need to send input fields and files, those values the blob and string are just for testing. I cannot send my data in JSON, I need to send a file with the input values

Comment: req.body.[key] is showing undefined, so I cannot access anything with this string that's not being parsed

Comment: if you need file uploads then use multer etc, then it will be in req.files

Comment: but I dont need files only. I need input values and a file. mutler showed me the same thing when I tried to get the input values of the form.

Comment: files wil be in files and values will be normal req.body, i.e `req.body.testing2`, there is many dupes/solutions [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+file+with+FormData+to+express+site:stackoverflow.com):

Comment: yes req.body.testing2 shows undefined

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions and nothings working